# Unit testing under test artifacts in build variants missing in IntelliJ Idea CE 14.1.4

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a multi-module Android gradle project which I run in IntelliJ 14.1.4. In the app module of my project, I have some unit tests. The build.gradle file of app project looks like follows:

**build.gradle (app)**

```
...

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['tests']
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
}
```

**directory structure (app)**

```
--app/
-----src/
-----res/
-----tests/
-----jniLibs/
```

I am using android gradle build tool version 1.2.3 (which is newer than 1.1.0 as suggested by IntelliJ to enable unit testing).

Even with these settings I am unable to get the unit testing under test artifacts in build variants window. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use android gradle build tool version 1.3.1 (or above). Include this line in the top level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        ...
    }
}
```

And magically, 'Unit Tests' will start appearing under 'Build Variants' window.

Comment: They didn't. is it because I also have another project included ? It is a multi project build.gradle?

Comment: @QuadroQ: gradle build tool is defined in top level build.gradle, you can have multiple modules in the same project.

Comment: It is defined there, but still can't run them.

Answer (score 1):

added this in the gradle and it fixed the issue for me.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart IntelliJ after creating the test folders.